# Empty line missing after using echo and sed

Tags: bash, shell

I have written one shell script which replaces some properties in a properties file.But after the script is run there is no empty line at the end of file which was present before replacement.

```
file=my_file.properties
file_content=$(cat $file | sed "s@a=.*@a=b@g") #making a=b
file_content=$(echo "${file_content}" | sed "s@x=.*@x=y@g") #making x=y
echo "${file_content}" > $file
```

my_file.properties is something like

```
 1)a=v
 2)b=c
 3)x=b
 4)
```

Note there is blank line at the end.These numbers are just for displaying the empty line

Comment: Add some sample content of file `my_file.properties` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) in reference to `$(…)` [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (emphasis mine):

> Bash performs the expansion by executing *command* in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.

So rather than capturing the output of the commands into a variable, you should capture them into a temporary file:

```
sed "s@a=.*@a=b@g" $file | sed "s@x=.*@x=y@g" > tmp.tmp
mv tmp.tmp $file
```

Or if you are using GNU sed, you can do it in one line:

```
sed -i -e "s@a=.*@a=b@g" -e "s@x=.*@x=y@g" $file
```

The `-i` means to edit the file in place, so no temporary file is needed.

Comment: Also, there is almost never a reason to actually use `cat` in a script.

Comment: why, how do you get the contents of file

Comment: `cat filename | sed ...` involves two processes, `sed ... filename` does the same thing and only requires one.